# Git Bash date command ignoring TZ env

Tags: bash, datetime, localization, git-bash, ksh

The `date(1)` command is supposed to take its timezone from the TZ environment variable.

Here's an example from the manpage:

```
68 mak:> date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles" 09:00 next Fri'
Fri Oct 20 09:00:00 GMT 2023
```

Taking a variation:

```
69 mak:> TZ='America/Los_Angeles' date
Mon Oct 16 16:03:03 GMT 2023
```

Except as you can see, in both cases, `date(1)` reported out using 'GMT'. In my case, I ran these commands at 11:03am in America/Chicago.

What I expected was times expressed via the TZ:

```
108 mak:> date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles" 09:00 next Fri'
Fri Oct 20 11:00:00 CDT 2023
```

And:

```
109 mak:>  TZ='America/Los_Angeles' date
Mon Oct 16 09:46:44 PDT 2023`
```

Comment: You've tagged [tag:git-bash] -- are you actually on Windows?

Comment: What's the output of `type -a date`? And `date --version`

Comment: no I'm running gitbash on windows.

Comment: 115 mak:> type -a date
date is /usr/bin/date
date is /bin/date

Comment: 116 mak:> date --version
date (GNU coreutils) 8.32

Comment: 117 mak:> uname -a
MINGW64_NT-10.0-22621 paco 3.3.6-341.x86_64 2022-09-05 20:28 UTC x86_64 Msys

Comment: It looks like the `date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles" 09:00 next Fri'` from the manual is a bug. I suspect the intended code is `TZ="America/Los_Angeles" date --date='09:00 next Fri'`

Answer (score 1):

So even though the TZ was set, date(1) ran home to GMT, because on gitbash the default directory for the zoneinfo data was empty.

to solve this, I grabbed the data from a [zoneinfo repo on github](https://github.com/stardemo/zoneinfo) and copied the zoneinfo directory to /use/share/zoneinfo

```
112 mak@:> ll -d /usr/share/zoneinfo/*
drwxr-xr-x 1 mak 197121     0 Oct 16 11:30 /usr/share/zoneinfo/Africa/
drwxr-xr-x 1 mak 197121     0 Oct 16 11:30 /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/
drwxr-xr-x 1 mak 197121     0 Oct 16 11:30 /usr/share/zoneinfo/Antarctica/
drwxr-xr-x 1 mak 197121     0 Oct 16 11:30 /usr/share/zoneinfo/Arctic/
drwxr-xr-x 1 mak 197121     0 Oct 16 11:30 /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/
drwxr-xr-x 1 mak 197121     0 Oct 16 11:30 /usr/share/zoneinfo/Atlantic/
drwxr-xr-x 1 mak 197121     0 Oct 16 11:30 /usr/share/zoneinfo/Australia/
drwxr-xr-x 1 mak 197121     0 Oct 16 11:30 /usr/share/zoneinfo/Brazil/
...
```

to double check, I verified that the magic number for these (binary) files was as I expected:

```
114 mak:> file  /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago
/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago: timezone data (fat), version 2, 7 gmt time flags, 7 std time flags, no leap seconds, 236 transition times, 7 local time types, 24 abbreviation chars
```

and date(1) immediately found the data and employed it to get the correct results.

```
110 mak:> echo $TZ
America/Chicago
111 mak:> date
Mon Oct 16 12:08:11 CDT 2023
```

another double check on the --date switch behavior:

```
119 mak:> TZ=America/New_York date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles" 09:00 next Fri'
Fri Oct 20 12:00:00 EDT 2023
```